# Custom Models in Process Engineering

Tags: modeling, process-engineering, software, pi-diagram

I'm using Aspen Custom Modeler to create a model to be used in Aspen Plus and Aspen Plus Dynamics, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to code the mass balance, energy balance, etc. I'm essentially coding up a pump, but a pump which takes both flow and inlet pressure as arguments to determine the outlet pressure. My model code is as follows.

```
Model XePump

  In1 as input MainPort;
  Out1 as output MainPort;

  // Internal
  Pdiff             as press_diff               (description:"Pressure difference");
  Svar              as fraction                 (1.0,fixed,description:"Operating speed parameter");  

  Pdiff = 1.0 * In1.P * (0.16169605386 - In1.F) * Svar;
  Out1.P = In1.P + Pdiff;
  Out1.F = In1.F;

End
```

The errors I'm getting are in Aspen Plus, the model doesn't have any outlet flow rate, despite explicitly setting it to be equal to the inlet flow rate. Any tips?